# sysv shared memory, will it be destroyed automatically?

Tags: c, system, shared-memory, sysv

Will shared memory allocated in Unix get destroyed automatically if you don't do that ?

e.g one process created that segment, another process take use of it. now they're both crashed for some reason, was that segment causing a memory leak ?

Comment: If both processes close, the memory will probably be reclaimed by the operating system.

Comment: Assumptions are the root of many bugs.  Allocate a huge chunk shared memory, verify using `vmstat` that you can see it allocated, then cause your program to crash.  Make sure it's gone.

Comment: Though it looks like, depending on how the memory was allocated, that might not be true.

Comment: How are you allocating the shared memory block?

Answer (score 4):

Generally not.

If you're using SysV shared memory (e.g, `shm_open`), then no. None of the SysV IPC primitives will clean themselves up; you always have to explicitly clean them up, or do so manually with `ipcrm`. This is one of several reasons that I recommend strongly against using them.

If you're `mmap`ping a file to get shared memory, that file obviously won't go away on its own. Like any other file, you'd have to explicitly `unlink` it to make it go away. If you've already done that, then you're all set.

Comment: To clarify: failing to unlink a mapped file does *not* lock down the allocated memory for all time.  Mapped regions can be paged (or swapped) out at any time, and obviously will be if the region is unused by live processes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the persistence you give the segment. As a rule of thumb, if you give it a name through `shm_open` (or a key) it will be persistent. As that indicates it will persist after you close the process that created it, unless you somehow "delete" it, that is do an `shm_unlink`. This is the only way you can share segments between completely different processes.

So if you do that you really have to take care to clean things up. The best strategy for such persistent segments is to have all processes open an file descriptor initially, and then to unlink as soon as everybody is connected. The segment will exist until the last file descriptor to it is closed.

Non-persistent segments can be mapped anonymously directly with `mmap`. They will go away as your process ceases to exist.

Answer (score 0):

No. Allocated shared memory segments should be discarded explicitly.

Useful command line tools for listing of shred memory segments and removing:
`ipcs` and `ipcrm`.
The last one can be used for ex. for removing a segment when all programs,using it, have crashed.